# How to check if a string is binary in Java

Tags: java, string, loops, binary

```
   /**
     * Given a String as input, return true if the String represents a valid
     * binary value (i.e. contains only the digits 1 and 0). Returns false if
     * the String does not represent a binary value.
     *
     * @param value
     *            A String value that may contain a binary value
     * @return true if the String value contains a binary value, false otherwise
     */
```

No matter what I do it only returns false. I am new to programming and suck at seeing how the logic runs. 
Thank you for any and all help.

```
public static boolean validBinary(String value) {

    int b = Integer.parseInt(value);
    int binCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        int tempB = value.charAt(i);
        if(tempB % 10 == 0 || tempB % 10 == 1) {
            binCount = binCount + 1;
        }
        else {
            binCount = -1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (binCount > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use regular expressions?

Comment: @Marvin I doubt it (or rather it may not be forbidden, but it's not the expected solution). These kinds of assignments are usually meant to teach logical thinking. So while the answers provided here solve the problem, they don't help the learner.

Comment: if ((tempB == '0') || (tempB == '1')) {binCount = binCount + 1;} else...

Comment: With your loops, why not check each char is '0' or '1' ?

Comment: `return value.matches("^[01]+$")`

Comment: You are calculating modulo of ASCII codes in the **decimal** system.

Comment: Please stop deleting this question!

Comment: @Marvin I am note sure what a regular expression is. In the assignment details it wants us to use a charAt() in the solution. I hope that answers the question.

Comment: @Johannes Kuhn I have not see that used in class before so I don't think I can use it. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: @PM77-1 I am not sure what that means.

Comment: @NomadMaker I get a out of bounds exception when I do that.

Comment: String x="100020";
    x = x.replace("1","").replace("0","");
    return x.length() == 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is step by step analysis of your program.

```
public static boolean validBinary(String value) {
```

Get rid of the following as it is not used.

```
    int b = Integer.parseInt(value);
```

Initializing `binCount` and starting the loop.

```
    int binCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        int tempB = value.charAt(i);
```

This is where the problem starts. Even though `tempB` is declared an `int` it still has the value of an ASCII character.  So '0' thru '9' are really 48 thru 57 inclusive.  So instead of converting to integers, just compare them as they exist which are characters.  In that case you can forget the % operator. So
the new if statement should be:

```
    if (tempB == '0' || tempB == '1') {
```

instead of

```
    if(tempB % 10 == 0 || tempB % 10 == 1) {
```

Keep the rest of your code and the program should work just fine.

```
      binCount = binCount + 1;
    }
    else {
            binCount = -1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (binCount > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Possible Improvements

The whole point of the exercise is to validate whether the number is binary.  So you don't need any bookkeeping such as `bincount` do do that.  As soon as your test for `0` or `1` fails, just return `false`.  No need for further processing.  But if you finish checking the entire string and haven't failed the test, then all the characters must be 0 or 1. So return `true`.  That would look like this.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        int tempB = value.charAt(i);
        if (tempB == '0' || tempB == '1') {
             continue; // process next character.
                       // continue skips rest of loop
         }
         return false;
   }
   // no failures, so
   return true;
```

Alternative logic without the `continue` could be:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        int tempB = value.charAt(i);
        if (tempB != '0' && tempB != '1') {
             return false;
         }
   }
   // no failures, so
   return true;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help in seeing the logic and fixing my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue is here: `int tempB = value.charAt(i);` You convert tempB into a char, which is being cast to an int. But that converts it to its ASCII int value, so each '0' char is cast to 48 and each '1' value is cast to 49. Note: neither 48 nor 49 is zero or one mod 10, so nothing is ever being added to bin.

You need to convert each char to its actual integer value (namely, zero or one), with String.valueOf or Character.getNumericValue:

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-char-to-int

Otherwise (besides the fact that you never use the b variable anywhere, so don't really need it) your logic looks pretty sound.

Comment: Thank you for the help. When I change tempB into char tempB = value.charAt(i) I get an out of bounds for length. Am I not doing it right?

Comment: I should clarify: keep it as an int, but use a different way to cast it from char to int: `int tempB = String.valueOf( value.charAt(i) );` or `int tempB = Character.getNumericValue( value.charAt(i) );`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a basic regular expression:

```
public static final String BIT_REGEX = "[01]{1,}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(BIT_REGEX);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
isValid = matcher.matches();
```

Answer (score -1):

public static boolean validBinary(String value) {

```
int binCount = 0;
int len = value.length();
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    char tempB = value.charAt(i);
    if(tempB == '0' || tempB == '1') {
        binCount = binCount + 1;
        continue;
    }
    else {
        binCount = -1;
        break;
    }
}
if (binCount > 0) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].